# How does Sidekiq testing in disable mode actually work?

Tags: sidekiq, minitest

My Sidekiq workers are like the example below:

```
Class BooksWorker
  include Sidekiq::Worker       
  def perform   
    books = Book.where(collected: true)
    books.each do |book|
      book.update_attribute(:status, "read")
      book.toggle!(:collected)
    end
  end
end
```

I would like to use Sidekiq testing in disable mode to check that:

1. jobs are enqueued
2. Sidekiq communicates with Redis (jobs are pushed to Redis)
3. jobs are retrieved from Redis and executed
4. jobs provide the expected results

What kind of test can I create to check all the four points above? 
Consider the example test below:

```
require 'test_helper'
require 'sidekiq/testing'

class BooksWorkerDisableTest < Minitest::Test
  def setup 
    configure = -> (config) do 
      config.redis = { url: 'redis://localhost:6379/15' } 
    end

    Sidekiq.configure_client(&configure)
    Sidekiq.configure_server(&configure)
    Sidekiq::Testing.disable!
    @books = Book.where(collected: true)
  end

  test "collected books should be marked as read before archived" do
    BooksWorker.perform_async
    @books.each do |book|
      assert book.status == "read"
      assert book.collected == false
    end
  end
end
```

If Sidekiq during the test enqueues the job, pushes to Redis, retrieves it from Redis and performs it, how long does it take for the test to be completed, assuming that the test is closed only after the job is performed?

The above test checks only the fourth point: how can I test the other points? I suppose it is only implicit that, if the jobs are performed, then they were already queued and pushed to Redis before.

Answer (score 2):

Your tests should test your code, not Sidekiq's.  Perform manual testing to verify everything is integrated.  disable mode can test 1 and 2, your tests can verify 4 directly.  3 is done manually.

Comment: Thanks. I suppose fake mode can test 1 and inline mode can test 4. Being a newbie I would not know how disable mode can test 2, and how can I perform manual testing for 3.